# How to apply security in windows form?

Tags: winforms, security

In windows forms, how can we track the login user, for example in web application we maintain session for that, after user login we maintain the "id" in session and we check in every page for that "id" using session, like that is there any way to do in window application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I maintain user login details in a Winforms application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186450/how-do-i-maintain-user-login-details-in-a-winforms-application)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so - and there is also no reason.

Sessions on Webservers are made for identifying a user (on it's session-id) over multiple-requests.