# how to maintain user information in different forms in windows application

Tags: c#, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I maintain user login details in a Winforms application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186450/how-do-i-maintain-user-login-details-in-a-winforms-application)

My project serves multiple users. When a user logs in, I want to retrieve `userid` of that user. The application shows some user details on several forms, so I would like to be able to pass the `userid` to that forms and than retrieve the user details.

In ASP.NET application we can use `Session` to store the user id. But how do I achieve the same functionality with Windows.Forms application?

Comment: Well.. that seem really simpler : in a windows application, you should have one user at a time (at least we expect one user per OS) so you can just use a static field...

Comment: You may also modify your [existing question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13582836/how-to-pass-user-values-into-different-forms-in-windows-application) rather then posting a new one

Comment: Really Thank you  Mr.habib ...I got the  answer throuh link you given